# Debugging in GPS IDE

Tags: ada, gnat-gps

I'm using GPS IDE for Ada 95 coding. When I try to put a break point in a .adb file, I'm getting a message "No source file named filename.adb". I built the project and initialized the debugger. What could have gone wrong?

Oddly, I'm able to execute the program.

Answer (score 8):

Did you enable the debug option for your project? Use Project/"Edit Project Properties" to open the project properties dialog, click the "Switches" tab. Then on each of the Gnatmake, Ada, and Ada Linker tabs check "Debug Information". Close the dialogs, then do a Build/Clean and rebuild your project. (Don't forget to save any changes, do Project/Save All.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to debug.